# What does which refer to?

Tags: relative-pronouns, exam-questions

Today I had an English exam (Egyptian GSEC English exam)

There was a passage about science fiction writing that said:

> Association with real-life events helps the author maintain the suspension of disbelief without *which*, the story becomes unrealistic....

So here what does the word which refer to? Does it refer to the suspension of belief or to the association with real-life events?

Comment: *Association with real-life events helps the author maintain the suspension of disbelief. Without **that suspension of disbelief** the story becomes unrealistic*. You could understand the reference as meaning *Without **that association** the story becomes unrealistic*, but this would be a bit perverse (though it's not obvious to me it would represent any significant difference in *meaning* anyway).

Comment: The antecedent of "which" is the nominal "suspension of disbelief".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Which* here is a relative pronoun.

Relative pronouns work more like conjunctions than actual pronouns.  They don't really have an antecedent but kinda-sorta "pull in" an entire previously expressed phrase and let it fill a subject or object slot in a following phrase.

> I told John that I didn't like it (allows "I didn't like that" to be object of "I told John X")
>
> I couldn't ever find out what Bobby's problem was (allows "Bobby's problem was" to be object of "I couldn't ever find out X")
>
> My cat ran away which meant that I didn't have to buy food. (*which* allows "My cat ran away" to be subject (X) of *X meant Y*, and *that* allows "I didn't have to buy food" to be object (Y) of "X meant Y*.)

In your example:

> Association with real-life events helps the author maintain the suspension of disbelief without which, the story becomes unrealisti

*Which* is allowing "the suspension of disbelief" to be the object of the preposition *without*.